# iPhone app: emoji unicode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unicode, emoji

I have a Json return that has a string that sometimes inludes something like **\Uf604** in the array (IE **memo = "\Uf604";**). I need to convert it to **\U0001F604** if possible.

I tried to do something like stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString but at that point when its in a string and it's been converted to **ÔòÑ** which I think it needs to be **üòÑ** to be displayed as a emoticon. I also tried

> [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Ô" withString:@"ü"];

But that didn't change anything. It still gets returned as ÔòÑ.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [I think this link has solution for your problem...][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365450/nsstring-with-unicode-issue-from-web-service?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I believe `str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Ô" withString:@"ü"];` is what you are trying to do.

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` doesn't change the string you are calling on but returns a new string with replaced characters.